# your svn client is too old error, how to fix it?

Tags: svn, fink

I'm fairly new to svn, and have installed the fink svn client for mac. I have used this for quite soe time, and suddenly it tells me that my client is too old to browse this repository.

In between uses of the fink client, I have also used a GUI application called svnx, but now that I wanted to use the command line tool again, it keeps giving me this error, even after redownloading fink.

Comment: has svnx changed any config that fink may be using? Have you removed svnx?

Comment: what's your version of fink's svn?

Comment: I'm using mac osx 10.5 on this laptop, so using fink 0.9.0
svnx version: 0.9.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the problem you need to refetch your repository from scratch using the client that you will use later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [python script (change-svn-wc-format.py)](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py) to downgrade your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a nice fix, but just making a new directory, and doing a checkout there worked fine. strange because I removed all files from the directory I tried to checkout into, (yes, also the hidden "." files)